# How to get LinkedIn Contacts or Friends List in Android?

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

Can any one help me to get LinkedIn Contacts or Friends or Connections List using LinkedIn API linkedin-j-android.jar.I am able to get all Current User Profile Information but don't know how to get Contacts or friends list.I have found a lot here on SO as well as on Google but still not got the Proper Solution yet.Please Someone Help me for my this issue.For that i have tried this.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    LinkedinDialog d = new LinkedinDialog(this, progressDialog);
    d.show();

    // set call back listener to get oauth_verifier value
    d.setVerifierListener(new OnVerifyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVerify(String verifier) {
            try {
                accessToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService
                        .getOAuthAccessToken(LinkedinDialog.liToken,
                                verifier);
                LinkedinDialog.factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
                client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
                // client.postNetworkUpdate("Testing by Mukesh!!! LinkedIn wall post from Android app");
                Loggger.i(TAG, "ln_access_token: " + accessToken.getToken());
                Loggger.i(TAG,
                        "ln_access_token: " + accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Person profile = client
                        .getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(
                                ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                                ProfileField.LAST_NAME,
                                ProfileField.CONNECTIONS));
                linkedInID = profile.getId();

                Loggger.i(TAG, "PersonID : " + linkedInID);
                linkedInFirstName = profile.getFirstName();
                linkedInLastName = profile.getLastName();
                Connections = profile.getConnections();
                Log.e(TAG, "CONNECTION : " + Connections);

                List<Contact> contactList;
                contactList = (ArrayList<Contact>) getIntent()
                        .getSerializableExtra("contact");
                for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
                    final Contact bean = contactList.get(i);
                    Log.d("Custom-UI",
                            "Display Name = " + bean.getDisplayName());
                    Log.d("Custom-UI",
                            "First Name = " + bean.getFirstName());
                    Log.d("Custom-UI", "Last Name = " + bean.getLastName());
                    Log.d("Custom-UI", "Contact ID = " + bean.getId());
                    Log.d("Custom-UI",
                            "Profile URL = " + bean.getProfileUrl());
                    Log.d("Custom-UI",
                            "Profile Image URL = "
                                    + bean.getProfileImageURL());
                    Log.d("Custom-UI", "Email = " + bean.getEmail());
                }

                Loggger.e(TAG, "connections  : " + Connections);
                Loggger.e(TAG, "linkedin firstname : " + linkedInFirstName);
                Loggger.e(TAG, "linkedin lastname : " + linkedInLastName);



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // set progress dialog
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

**The r_network scope recently changed to be a LinkedIn partner-only permission. You can apply for access to their partnership program here:**

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Answer (score 0):

1.Refer to this link : https://github.com/Hafiz-Waleed-Hussain/EasyLinkedInAndroid as library

2.In Main java layout use :

```
_EasyLinkedIn = EasyLinkedIn.getInstance(this, "api key",
                "secret key",
                "https://github.com/Hafiz-Waleed-Hussain/EasyLinkedInAndroid",
                "", "");

    _EasyLinkedIn.authorize(MainActivity.this, new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onSucess(Object data) {

            String fields = "id,first-name,headline";

            _EasyLinkedIn.getUserInfo(this, this, fields);

            String fields1 = "id";

            String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id=Gcn6gB9aCj)?format=json&oauth2_access_token="
                    + EasyLinkedIn.getAccessToken();
            _EasyLinkedIn.getConnections(this, this, fields1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {

        }
    });
```

onDownloadingComplete() method use log to print object paramter

Comment: do you have link to get native app linkedin access token in simple java class. Remember No activity class ??